# How to add a delete command button in devExpress gridview from codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am using DevExpress gridview that have a command button inside. I want to use image instead of it. How can be it possible?

Upto now I have tried this much :

```
GridViewCommandColumn commancol = new GridViewCommandColumn(); 
commancol.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image; 
GridViewCommandColumnButton moveUpBtn; 
moveUpBtn.Image.Url = "~/App_Themes/Images/GridControl/grid-delete.png"; 
commancol.Add(moveUpBtn);
```

But it is giving error.

I want to add a below way button from .cs page instead of aspx page. so i tried to above way from codebehind.

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn ButtonType="Image">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <DeleteButton Visible="true" Text="" Image-Url="grid-delete.png"
                Image-ToolTip="Delete Record">
            </DeleteButton>
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to add an image button on gridview in code behind

Comment: I am trying with below code but its give me error on "commancol.Add(moveUpBtn);" line

     GridViewCommandColumn commancol = new GridViewCommandColumn();
     commancol.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;
     GridViewCommandColumnButton moveUpBtn;
     moveUpBtn.Image.Url = "~/App_Themes/Images/GridControl/grid-delete.png";
     commancol.Add(moveUpBtn);

so how can i add a delete command button from .cs page..

Comment: i just want to add a delete command button from code behinde.. so how can i do this?

Comment: @sejalpatel please paste gridview's design as well as cs page code so that one can know what problem are you facing while adding image instead of command button in gridview.

Comment: @Dev i paste gridview button i want to add from codebehind instead of aspx page.

Comment: @sejalpatel you want to add the delete column also dynamically (from code behind)

Comment: @dev yes i want to add delete command button column from codebehind.

Comment: @sejalpatel the answers below are true, you can also try out this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486062/how-do-i-add-a-column-with-buttons-in-to-a-gridview-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [CommandColumn](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3701) simply as below, but you should take care about the asp.net page events to work it correct.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewCommandColumn column = new GridViewCommandColumn("....");
    column.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
    column.DeleteButton.Image.Url = "set path here";
    column.Visible = true;
    column.VisibleIndex = 2;//place where you want it to display
    ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(column); 
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Bind Data here
    BindData();
}
```

Refer the documentation of [Command Columns](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3701), then you can get another command button also and set their properties at run time as you want.

Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks.. i want to displayed image in grid and its displayed a delete link

Comment: @sejalpatel check the documentation link.. it will help you move further

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this,
1) in itemtemplate declare `imageButton` 
2) declare `commandname` and `commandargument`
3) declare getimagepath
4) declare at cs page getimage function as

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
    <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("") %>'
                            ImageUrl='<%#GetImagePath("delete.png")%>' Width="20" Height="20" OnClick="ibDelete_Click"
                            OnClientClick='<%# Eval("", "return confirm(\"Are you sure to delete - {0} ?\");") %>'
                            ToolTip="Delete Item" />
    </ItemTemplate>




public string GetImagePath(string imgName)
        {
            string Finalurl =  this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/images/" + imgName;
            return Finalurl;
        }
```

5) declare rowcommand like

```
protected void row_command(object sender, gridviewrowcommand e)
{
     if(e.commandname=="Delete")
      {
           if(e.commandargument!=null)
            {
                  // do the work here
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i want to add a below type delete command button from code behind.not from aspx page.

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn ButtonType="Image">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <DeleteButton Visible="true" Text="" Image-Url="grid-delete.png"
                    Image-ToolTip="Delete Record">
                </DeleteButton>
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn Name="deleteRow" ShowDeleteButton="True" VisibleIndex="3" ButtonType="Image">
                <CustomButtons>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton Visibility="AllDataRows" Image-Width="20" Image-Url="~/img/delete-icon.png"
                        Image-Height="20">
                        <Image Height="20px" Width="20px">
                        </Image>
                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
                </CustomButtons>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```