# Asp.net Gridview button before a row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a Gridview in asp.net with information from a SQL database, now I want to code the gridview so I can click on a row which redirects me to another aspx page where I can run a query with the information from that row.

For example I got a row with the following information:

```
- Arjen de Vries 123456789 Netherlands
```

Then I need like a detail button before that row like:

```
- (detail) Arjen de Vries 123456789 Netherlands
```

And when you click on detail it brings me to another page where you can find more information about me.

The first step is to create the detail button, but I have searched the internet but can't find the proper solution.

So my question is how do I create such a button, which is linked to the information in that row.

**First EDIT:**

I Found the solution to create button in my gridview, now when I click this button I get redirected to another page.

I found the solution on the page in the comments.

The following problem is now, how can I use the data in the gridview row to build a query on the next page?

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486062/how-do-i-add-a-column-with-buttons-in-to-a-gridview-in-asp-net

Comment: It helped me to create the button but not to set the behavior of the button.

Comment: you can use row events of gridview for your purpose.

Comment: How? For example, when i click my button now i want to go to another page with a gridview that runs a sql-query that ends with: WHERE naam = 'Arjen de Vries' Where he gets the name out of the previous gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!

Firstly i want to thank Anshu again, i used parts of his code. What i did was: i created a session for the string firstColData  = grdrow.Cells[0].Text;

then on my other page i did : sqldatasource.selectcommand "SELECT ... From ... WHERE naam = '" + session.["Thesessionname"].tostring() + "'";

That was what i wanted to achieve.

Thanks to u all!

Answer (score 0):

Following example is for a link button, but there's no difference for normal button. 
Link button will definitly look better in a gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="tblcss1" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="grdCustomPagging_RowCommand">
 <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DB_COL_1" HeaderText="First Col" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DB_COL_2" HeaderText="second Col" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DB_COL_3" HeaderText="Third Col" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">

    <ItemTemplate>

   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkView" OnClick="lnkView_Click">Click here</asp:LinkButton>

     </ItemTemplate>

   </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

c# code is

```
protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;

    string firstColData  = grdrow.Cells[0].Text;
    string secondColData  =   grdrow.Cells[1].Text;
    string thirdColData  = grdrow.Cells[2].Text;

    Response.Redirect("page1.aspx?firstColumnValue="+firstColData );

}
```

Or you  can use a hyper link and send row values to the next page as a query string. In that page you can display the details. Unless you want to process data in the first page it is the better approch. If exposing data in the url is the issue, you can encrypt the query string.

Comment: If i understand it correctly ure code goes to page "a" when name = "a" and to "b" when name is "b" But i want to create 1 page where the datasource for the gridview just changes with the name in column 1.

Comment: First i want to thank u for all the effort u are making to help me. I followed ur code but it didn't do anything for me, the gridview on the other page has a select statement. Where he selects more details for the name in the text in the first cell. So the select statement has to adjust. How do i achieve that?

Comment: ok. So you want to carry the name to the next page and within that page you query using the name which is sent from the first page. And display the details.
Is this the requirement?