# Custom button for gridview using asp.net is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, visual-studio-2015

I've tried creating my own custom button in gridview using
asp.net. I wanted to replicate the usual delete button that
we use in gridview and then, adding new functionality like having
the ability to delete files stored in my visual studio 2015(which is
located in Documents). So when the admin clicks the delete button,
it will remove all the data within that row and delete the corresponding
file associated with it.

Let's say i wanted to delete all the info under id#10. I already 
have added a new button beside the default edit and delete links.

[image]

Now the problem is, when i click the delete button that I have created,
It is giving me this exception.

[image]

Here is also my code(the aspx file):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView20" runat="server" OnRowCommand="FireRowCommand" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3" DataKeyNames="id" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Height="250px" Width="864px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CommandName="cDelete" Text="Delete"></asp:Button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="model" HeaderText="model" SortExpression="model" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="image1" HeaderText="image1" SortExpression="image1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="image2" HeaderText="image2" SortExpression="image2" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GuitarItemsDBConnectionString2 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [guitarItemIbanez] WHERE [id] = @id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [guitarItemIbanez] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2]) VALUES (@id, @type, @model, @price, @image1, @image2)" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2] FROM [guitarItemIbanez]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [guitarItemIbanez] SET [type] = @type, [model] = @model, [price] = @price, [image1] = @image1, [image2] = @image2 WHERE [id] = @id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="model" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="image1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="image2" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="model" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="image1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="image2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is also another code(the aspx.cs file):

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 public partial class Pages_OverviewData : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GuitarItemsDBConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
private SqlConnection conn;
private SqlCommand cmd;
private SqlDataAdapter ad;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetData();
    }

}

private void GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    // get the connection
    using (conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
    {

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM guitarItemIbanez ORDER By id";

        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {

            using (ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {

                ad.Fill(table);
            }
        }
    }

    GridView20.DataSource = table;
    GridView20.DataBind();
}


protected void FireRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string command3 = e.CommandName;
    string autoId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    switch (command3)
    {
        case "cDelete":
            string query = string.Format(@"DELETE FROM [guitarItemIbanez] WHERE [id] = @id");
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            System.IO.File.Delete(@"C: \Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\GuitarItemsIbanez10.aspx");
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"C: \Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\GuitarItemsIbanez10.aspx.cs");
            break;
    }



    }

}
```

Comment: not sure about the code ,but the best way is to put <asp:button> inside the grid column for each row. click on it and get the row number. find the data of the particular row and perform the operation.

Comment: I'd highly appreciate it if you can give me an actual example. I'm still a beginner in making websites.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486062/how-do-i-add-a-column-with-buttons-in-to-a-gridview-in-asp-net
this link will provide  you exactly what you need